# Retrieving data using JDBC in utf-8 from a mysql server where charset is set to latin1

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, mysql-connector

The schema and tables all have charset and collation of Latin1, but if I try to retrieve Chinese characters from table, it only gives `?????`. I don't have access to change the schema or tables properties. How can I convert the charset to actual characters in JDBC?

Comment: Chinese characters won’t map to a Latin 1 encoding indicated by the `?`.  Your database strings are probably broken.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen do broken means, it can't be retrieved by any way?. is it possible to retrieve by setting charsetResult param in connection object?

Comment: Use the official tools for the database to look inside to verify that the data is correctly stored.  If no, you have bigger problems.

Comment: if I see in mysql workbench, there too the other language is ???. is there no way to get back the data?

Comment: I don't know but if the data was mangled when originally inserted in the database there is not much to do.  I would suggest examining the data closer to see if the actual bytes stored are what you need.